# CSS Horizontal Align Float

Tags: css, css-float, center, alignment, text-align

I have a simple menu and I want to place it in the center of the page using css.
Here's the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/kSV4K/4/

Here's the Codes, 
CSS:

```
ul#menu { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; }
ul#menu li { position:relative; float:left; border-bottom:4px solid #efefef; margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px;}
ul#menu .current { border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;}
ul#menu li:hover { border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;}
ul#menu li a { padding:2px 2px; text-decoration:none; font:bold 8px Verdana, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#68759c;}
ul#menu li a:hover { color:#8895b8; border:none; }
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I strongly advice to put more context into your fiddle : the styles applied to the container and surrounding elements may have an influence on the positioning of this. Also, note that ul#menu is somehow bad selection. You should only have 1 item with id "menu" on your page, so no need to prefix with ul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of floats, use inline-blocks on the `li` elements, and then they can be centered applying `text-align: center` on the `ul` block.

```
ul#menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom:4px solid #efefef;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/kSV4K/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can also add some width to the menu and apply `margin: 0 auto;` to center it here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/swT4F/ I also recommend your menu be contained inside a `<nav>` tag or a `<div>`.